# What is the best way to define a (maybe hierarchical) set of constants in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have to define a set of constants, like

```py
IMAGE_FOLDER="..."
MASKS_FOLDER="..."
OBJECTS_FOLDER="..."

IMAGE_FMT="...",
MASK_FMT="...",
OBJECT_FMT="...",

FORMATS=(IMAGE_FMT, MASK_FMT, OBJECT_FMT)

...
```

(The common use case is to save some string constants in a variable to not make typo error by typing "image" several times)

What would be the best way to define that (in case I have many of them). I can see several solutions like `types.SimpleNamespace` or create a custom class. But what if I want these constants to be assigned recursively, e.g. `constants.folder.image` instead of `constants.image_folder`

Is there any general practice or some better solution than a custom class?

**UPD**: the custom class solution looks like this

```py
class Constants:
    class Formats:
        OBJECT = "objects_format"
        MASK = "masks_format"

    class Folders:
        IMAGE = "images_folder"
        OBJECTS = "objects_folder"
        MASKS = "masks_folder"

    class Extensions:
        IMAGE = {".bmp", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".tif", ".tiff"}
        OBJECTS = {".xml"}
        MASKS = {".bmp", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".tif", ".tiff"}

    class DatasetColumns:
        ID = "ID"
        IMAGE = "image"
        OBJECTS = "object"
        MASK = "mask"
```

So the "recursive property" means that I can access recursively by dot like Constants.DatasetColumns.ID

The problem with this custom class solution is that these attributes are not really a constants. Maybe I do not really need them to be... but if you know how to make them constant with be directly accessed (without Enum's .value()) with approximately the same amount of code for the definition it will be probably the ideal solution

Comment: Alternatively, use a (constant) dict (where you may choose to only uppercase the dict name, not the keys when accessing items); some dict values may then be dicts themselves.

Comment: Or, perhaps better: use a namedtuple (as these are set-once, read-only).

Comment: That doesn't really sound like a constant

Comment: @00 yeah, namedtuple is almost what I wanted, but it has no recursive property

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by recursive propery (you can embed a namedtuple in a namedtuple, for example), but if you intend to create things on the fly, you can't really call it a constant anymore, can you?

Comment: To take your example, you would make folder a `constants` a namedtuple (with a `folder` item), and `folder` a namedtuple with an `image` item, and declare that up-front at the top of your code. (Your example suggests `constants` is a module, but the idea is the same.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may reaching for an [enumeration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

```
from enum import Enum

class Formats(Enum):
    IMAGE = "..."
    MASK = "..."
    OBJECT = "..."

class Folders(Enum):
    IMAGE = "..."
    MASKS = "..."
    OBJECTS = "..."
```

Comment: hmm, good advice, but I can see 2 "drawbacks": 1) I will have to use *.value 2) I will have to define sereval such entities instead of a single entity

Comment: @asmekal how could you avoid defining several? I'd imagine you'd have to type all of the string constants into your code, unless there's a property of the string values you haven't told us. If they have a pattern, edit your question to add it.

Comment: @DanGetz yes, sure, I have to type all of the strings, that's correct. In the above comment "2)" I meant that in this enum solution I will have several entities (several Enums available by public name) and I probably wanted to see only one object.
but this is a "drawback" - in quotes, which means it is not really severe drawback

Comment: to avoid 2) the enums can be placed into single class

Comment: If there is no logical order in the strings, enumerations are not a logical choice. For a set of colours, it'd be fine, but with `IMAGE = "picture"; MASK = "grey"; OBJECT="dog"`, enumeration doesn't make sense (or flags). If the constants are anything other than an enumeration or (bit)flags, I would not use `Enum`.