# How do I organize hierarchical string constants with dot notation in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a Python client that hits an HTTP endpoint. The endpoints have a tree structure, where almost any point could also be an endpoint. I would like to be able to hit any of the points along that hierarchy and have it build a string based on the constants defined.

For example, I would like `Endpoints.CONFIGURATION` to expand to `/configuration`, and also `Endpoints.CONFIGURATION.ACTIVE` to expand to `/configuration/active`.

I would like to do this programmatically so I can write less code. I would also like to avoid defining these as functions that the end user has to call, so possibly some sort of class these all derive from with an override to `__str__` would be ideal.

I tried manipulating Python's class system to accomplish something like this. Given the example above, what I wrote was

```
class EndpointClass:
    class CONFIGURATION:
        ACTIVE = '/configuration/active'
```

However, this is missing the functionality I defined where I would need `.CONFIGURATION` to expand to `/configuration`. I also had to manually write `/configuration` where I would prefer to have it autoexpand based on the class it is defined in.

I considered a dictionary-based solution, but as far as I know, that wouldn't allow for dot notation with autocomplete, and might not return values for any level of the hierarchy.

I considered [What is the best way to define a (maybe hierarchical) set of constants in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59091560/what-is-the-best-way-to-define-a-maybe-hierarchical-set-of-constants-in-python) but it doesn't have as deep of a hierarchy as I may reach, and it doesn't have autoexpansion, and it doesn't support stopping at different levels of the hierarchy and still getting something back.

Comment: Are the layers arbitrarily deep?

Comment: Yes, the layers should be able to become arbitrarily deep. I think the deepest we have in practice now is seven, but it may become deeper.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can't you just remove the `Endpoints` prefix and then replace the `.` with `/`?

Comment: We want this to be something that has autocomplete/intellisense at coding time. Some less experienced developers will be coming into contact with this, and we want to make it as simple for them as possible by handling everything under the hood, and by defining these as constants in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for?  It is a simple parent/child tracking class that enables dot-completion for the children items.  It also expands an endpoint's ancestral chain when passing to `str`.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

class Endpoint:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self._name = name
        self._children = {}
        self._parent = None

    def __dir__(self) -> Iterable[str]:
        cls_attrs = object.__dir__(self)
        return [n for n in self._children] + cls_attrs
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'<Endpoint({self._name!r})>'
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self._parent:
            up = f'{str(self._parent)}/'
        else:
            up = ''
        return f'{up}{self._name.lower()}'
    
    def append_endpoint(self, endpoint_name: str):
        if any(c.lower()==endpoint_name for c in self._children):
            raise KeyError(f'A sub-endpoint {endpoint_name!r} already exists.')
        new_endpoint = self.__class__(endpoint_name)
        new_endpoint._parent = self
        self._children[endpoint_name] = new_endpoint

    def __getattr__(self, _attr: str):
        if _attr in self._children:
            return self._children[_attr]
        return object.__getattribute__(self, _attr)
    
    def __iadd__(self, endpoint_name: str):
        if not isinstance(endpoint_name, str):
            return NotImplemented
        self.append_endpoint(endpoint_name)
        return self
```

Using the class looks like:

```
config = Endpoint('CONFIGURATION')
config += 'ACTIVE'         # ACTIVE will appear in the dot completion
config.ACTIVE += 'LAST'
config += 'INACTIVE'
config.INACTIVE += 'HISTORY'
config.INACTIVE.HISTORY += 'Y2020'
config.INACTIVE.HISTORY += 'Y2021'
config.INACTIVE.HISTORY += 'Y2022'
config.INACTIVE.HISTORY += 'Y2023'

str(config.ACTIVE.LAST)
# returns: 'configuration/active/last'
```

Comment: Firstly, based on your profile picture and username (and your sense of humor on your profile), I think you may have been one of my teachers for a short period of time. Thank you for responding to this post. Secondly, although this is close to what I am looking for, I am looking for something with dot completion before runtime - after some further research, I am not sure that this is possible with namespaces or iterables in VS Code. Either that, or I have my settings misconfigured for this particular solution.

Comment: @stack-wizard I don't think it is a VS code issue, rather more a limitation of the Python language.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a bit hackish solution, but it does what you want.

```
class Notation(type):
    def __str__(cls):
        return '/' + cls.__qualname__.casefold().replace(".", "/")


class CONFIGURATION(metaclass=Notation):
    class ACTIVE(metaclass=Notation):
        pass


print(f"CONFIGURATION = {CONFIGURATION}")
print(f"CONFIGURATION.ACTIVE = {CONFIGURATION.ACTIVE}")

# Output:
# CONFIGURATION = /configuration
# CONFIGURATION.ACTIVE = /configuration/active
```

A less hackish way is perhaps to use underscores for hierarchy e.g.

```
CONFIGURATION = '/configuration'
CONFIGURATION_ACTIVE = '/configuration/active'
...
```